# Gnuplot: How to draw an opposing bar plot or pyramid bar diagram

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to use two positive y-axes with gnuplot? This is just a simple example for the question.

**plot.gp:**

```
reset
set style fill solid 1
set boxwidth 0.8 relative
plot 'data1.dat' index 1 using 1:2     with boxes title 'A' ,\
              '' index 2 using 1:(-$2) with boxes title 'B'
```

Instead of using `1:(-$2)` I would like to use `1:2` in the last line in plot.gp.

**data1.dat:**

```
0.12   0.024
0.15   0.132
0.18   0.241
0.22   0.136


0.12   0.039
0.15   0.219
0.18   0.197
0.22   0.155
```

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `multiplot`? With this you can get a solution for sure. I will think about if there might be a solution even without `multiplot`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I have not tried multiplot yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as the one from *theoz* except that the y2 labels are shifted to the left side of the plot and the `set link y2` command is used to generalize the axis inversion.

You can tweak the offset `graph -1.03` to superimpose the "0" labels, then delete the duplicate "0" label by changing the y2 tic range to `set y2tics 0.1,0.1`.

```
$Data <<EOD
0.12   0.024
0.15   0.132
0.18   0.241
0.22   0.136


0.12   0.039
0.15   0.219
0.18   0.197
0.22   0.155
EOD

set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set xzeroaxis ls -1

set yrange[-0.3:0.3]
set ytics 0,0.1
set mytics 2

# Set y2 axis to exact mirror of y1
# Shift tic labels to the left and use right-justified text
set link y2 via -y inv -y
set y2tics 0,0.1
set y2tics offset graph -1.03 right

plot $Data u 1:2 index 0 axis x1y1 w boxes title 'A' ,\
        '' u 1:2 index 1 axis x1y2 w boxes title 'B'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a single plot, however, the y-axis tics are on different sides.
Maybe there is some easy way to get them on the same side.

**Code:**

```
### two "positive" y-axes
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.12   0.024
0.15   0.132
0.18   0.241
0.22   0.136


0.12   0.039
0.15   0.219
0.18   0.197
0.22   0.155
EOD

set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.8 relative

set yrange[-0.3:0.3]
set ytics 0,0.1
set mytics 2
set y2range[0.3:-0.3]
set y2tics 0,0.1
set my2tics 2
set y2tics mirror
set xzeroaxis ls -1

plot $Data u 1:2 index 0 axis x1y1 w boxes title 'A' ,\
        '' u 1:2 index 1 axis x1y2 w boxes title 'B'
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Here is a second suggestion with all ytic labels on one side.
A little drawback is that it is not autoscale and you have to set the range and the steps "manually".
It is using the command `evaluate` (check `help evaluate`). And `real()` (check `help real`) in order to avoid gnuplot's integer division in case the two numbers of the division might be integers.

**Code:**

```
### y-axis with two "positive" directions
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.12   0.024
0.15   0.132
0.18   0.241
0.22   0.136


0.12   0.039
0.15   0.219
0.18   0.197
0.22   0.155
EOD

set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set xzeroaxis ls -1

Max = 0.3
Steps = 3
set yrange[-Max:Max]
set ytics ()            # remove all tics
do for [i=-Steps:Steps] {
    myTic = sprintf('set ytics add ("%g" %g)',abs(real(i)/Steps*Max),real(i)/Steps*Max)
    eval(myTic)
}

plot $Data u 1:2     index 0 axis x1y1 w boxes lc 3 title 'A' ,\
        '' u 1:(-$2) index 1 axis x1y1 w boxes lc 4 title 'B'
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Move the y2 tic labels to the left side: `set y2tics offset graph -1.03 right`.  You may have to tweak the value `1.03` to make the "0" labels exactly superimpose.

Comment: @Ethan ah, interesting. I haven't thought of  `offset` and that you can do it in `graph` coordinates. As you say, drawback is that it depends on the graph size, so every time you change the graph size you have to tweak again. I will add another idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.